# why the set $A=\{(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{R}:x-y\in E\}$ is $\mathcal{B}\times\mathcal{B}$-measurable

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

If $E\in\mathcal{B}$ , then the set $A=\{(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{R}:x-y\in E\}$ is $\mathcal{B}\times\mathcal{B}$-measurable, where $\mathcal{B}$ is the family of Borel subsets of $\mathbb{R}$

I can figure out it as the lines which parametrized by the elements of $E$. But I couldn't conclude that $A$ is $\mathcal{B}\times\mathcal{B}$-measurable. My definitions are the following:  $\mathcal{B}$ is the $\sigma$-algebra generated by the open sets in $\mathbb{R}$   and $\mathcal{B}\times\mathcal{B}$ is the $\sigma$-algebra generated by Borel-rectangles. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider the map
$$
\phi:\mathbb R\times \mathbb R\rightarrow \mathbb R,\ (x,y) \mapsto x-y.
$$
$\phi$ is continuous and hence Borel-measurable. That's a "well known" fact from measure theory. Now we conclude
$$
A = \phi^{-1}(E) \in \mathcal{B}\times\mathcal{B},
$$
as desired.